# SQL Server Data Tools Code analysis not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution containing multiple SSDT projects and I recently enabled a number of code analysis rules for them. This solution builds fine on my machine without warnings, but a colleague of mine gets warnings when building the same solution.

I looked at the warnings and they are correct. All warnings appear to be a case of a procedure calling a procedure in another project. If I put that procedure in the same project as the procedures it calls, I get the errors as well.

For example: Project A and B. Project A has a procedure A1 which calls a procedure B1 in project B. I get no warning, but my colleague does. If I put procedure A1 in project B, I also get a warning.

An example of a warning I get is as follows:

> Warning 18 SR0014 : Microsoft.Rules.Data : Data loss might occur when casting from VarChar(100) to VarChar(50).

What could cause my build to not see these warnings?

More things I've been able to discover:

Person A runs SSDT version 12.0.30919.1
Person B runs SSDT version 12.0.30919.1
Person C runs SSDT version 12.0.40403.0

All persons have the same database project in visual studio 2013 shared trough SVN

When Person A compiles the database project, he gets warnings. such as
`Warning 18 SR0014 : Microsoft.Rules.Data : Data loss might occur when casting from VarChar(100) to VarChar(50).`

When Person B compiles the database project, he does NOT any warnings fo things such as casting with possible data loss.

When Person C compiles the database project, he also does NOT get any warnings.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the version number because person A and person B have the same version number. Additionally, this happened:

Person A upgrades from SSTD version 12.0.30919.1 to SSDT 12.0.40403.0

Now when person A compiles, he does NOT get any warnings for things such as casting VarChar(100) to VarChar(50)

It might be possible that the problem isn't necessarily a version problem, but a problem with the upgrade process itself.

Comment: You probably haven't set up the rules in your project A. [See](http://mikefourie.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/visual-studio-database-edition-2010-%E2%80%93-static-code-analysis-review-part-1/)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty As far as I know, the Rules are the same in both Projects, our source control can't find any differences.

Comment: Are you both running the same version of SSDT? There were changes to Code Analysis in the latest March release. That'll be shown as version 12.0.40403.0 of SQL Server Data Tools in the "Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio" dialog. If there is a bug in the newer version where it doesn't detect errors with project references please raise this as a product bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx and use the category "Developer Tools(SSDT, BIDS, etc.)". I work on the product team and we can investigate it best when raised through Connect.

Comment: @KevinCunnane I can confirm that updating from 12.0.30919.1 to 12.0.40403.0 hides/doesn't show the errors. Is there any way to downgrade my ssdt version?

Comment: @KevinCunnane I've added the also put the error bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/906446/sql-server-data-tools-code-analysis-not-working-correctly

be sure to click on details

Comment: Thanks, I've reproduced this and found the root cause. Unfortunately this has missed the cutoff date for our next release but we'll look at fixing it in a future release. We'll update the connect bug with information so that's the best place to look.

Comment: @KevinCunnane I see, that might take a while, since you're the expert, can you think of any workwarounds I could employ to resolve this problem?